# How to find by on the reference key related other table field(using JPA)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

For example, table A has primary key id, referenced id is bid; table B also has primary key id equal to bid, filedB and more.

My question is that by using Java JPA how to find by B.fieldB?

```
ADAO extends CrudRepository{
   findBy(____);//find by referenced bid related table's fieldB.
}
```

Entity class example:

```
@Entity @Table(name="A") public class A implements Serializable{ id; bid; };

@Entity @Table(name="B") public class B implements Serializable{ id; fieldB; }
```

Comment: What do your entity classes look like?  Post their code.

Comment: (at)Entity
(at)Table(name="A")
public class A implements Serializable{ id; bid; }; (at)Entity
(at)Table(name="B")
public class B implements Serializable{ id; fieldB; }

Comment: Post full code for classes `A` and `B` in the question itself.  We need to see how you have modeled the relationship between `A` and `B` in the Java code.

Comment: You cannot query directly for `A` based on that class model.  You need to have a field of type `B` inside `A`.  If you had `class A { Long id; @JoinColumn(name = "bid") @ManyToOne B b; }`, you could have the query method `interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> { List<A> findByBFieldB(String fieldB) }`.  This will automatically get translated to something like `SELECT a.* FROM A a, B b WHERE a.bid = b.id AND b.fieldB = ?`.

Comment: @manish: that's work for me. Thanks! But I have to choose another way (history code maintain issue) by using: @Query(value = "SELECT a.* FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.bid=b.id WHERE b.field LIKE :someString", nativeQuery = true);

Answer (score 0):

According to @manish suggestion, that's worked on my side.

First off, using annotation to define the relation ship between A and B;

```
@Entity @Table(name="A") public class A implements Serializable{ id; bid;
@JoinColumn(name = "bid") @ManyToOne B b;
 };

@Entity @Table(name="B") public class B implements Serializable{ id; fieldB; }
```

Then `findByBFieldB(string fieldB)` in my A-Repository;

Another way: using annotated query as following:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT a.* FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.bid=b.id WHERE b.field LIKE :someString", nativeQuery = true);
```

I wish I could do as well.